# localtime not thread safe, but okay to call in only one thread?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Am integrating another users code into mine.  They have library that calls localtime function which is not thread safe.

I have noticed some strange problems.   If their code is restricted to one thread only can localtime still cause a problem?  Note in other threads of my code I call localtime_r ( the thread safe version ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

The reason `localtime` is not threadsafe is that it stores the result (`struct tm *`) in a static variable. So as long as you only call this function from a single thread, it shouldn't cause problems.

In other words, `localtime` looks something like this:

```
struct tm *localtime(time_t *timer)
{
   static struct tm tt;
   ... many lines that sets tt member variables ... 
   return &tt;
}
```

Obviously, if two threads call this function, then the value in returned pointer will change "randomly" based on which thread last called `localtime()` and what the value in `timer` is.

The function `localtime_r` is safe because it takes a `struct tm *` as an argument, and returns a pointer to that variable. And in fact, the above is how `localtime` USED to be implemented. So, if the code for `localtime_r` looks a bit like this:

```
struct tm *localtime_r(time_t *timer, struct tm *result)
{
   ... many lines that sets result member variables ... 
   return result;
}
```

and now, of course, we can make a much shorter version of `localtime`:

```
struct tm *localtime(time_t *timer)
{
   static struct tm tt;
   return localtime_r(timer, &tt); 
}
```

Edit2: It is of course CRITICAL that the `result` argument of `localtime_r` is unique to the thread calling it. Having a `static` or global variable for this argument will make it very much the same problem as before.

Edit3: Of course there is another way to make it go wrong:

```
struct tm *a, *b;
... 
a = localtime(something);
... 
b = localtime(someother);

if (a->tm_sec != b->tm_sec) 
{
   ... this never happens ... 
}
```

In this case, `a` and `b` will point to exactly the same place. The same applies if the same variable is used for `localtime_r` and different pointers are used to receive the data and the expectation is that the pointers are pointing at different things.

Comment: What if only one thread calling localtime?  Then okay for other threads to call localtime_r?

Comment: @Tolga are you implying that my answer is wrong? `localtime` should be fine to call from ONE thread, no matter what any other threads are doing.

Comment: @Tolga: Although I have made a clarification. You can get into all sorts of bother if you expect the pointer returned from `localtime` (an possibly `localtime_r`) to be different at each call. But you should not need to use mutexes within one thread when calling `localtime`, if the use of the result isn't conflicting like in Edit3.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I have read the answer in really wrong way regarding localtime_r part. Removed my comment.